# Context value / variable not rendered inside blocktrans template tag

Tags: django-templates, django-i18n

I've a context processor which adds objects (i.e. `site`) to the template context but the value is not rendered inside the `{% blocktrans %}` template tag. Outside the template tag, the value prints just fine.

```
<h1>{% trans "About" %} {{ site.domain }}</h1> <!-- works -->

{% blocktrans %}
   {{ site.domain }} <!-- doesn't work -->
{% endblocktrans %}
```

How do I get the object's attribute / variable to render inside `{% blocktrans %}`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Interpolated variables cannot be dotted expressions - you need something like this:

```
{% blocktrans with site_domain=site.domain %}{{ site_domain }} is a ...{% endblocktrans %}
```

See also:

- [Django documentation: blocktrans template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag)
- [Question: django blocktrans and i18n in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813516/)

Comment: Should I need to deactivate() previous language?  because I used same above tag but still its not translating.

Comment: Just in case anyone's wondering (as I was): If you need to specify multiple variables the syntax is to seperate the definitions with a space. Like so: `{% blocktrans with foo_bar=foo.bar spam_eggs=spam.eggs %}...{% endblocktrans %}`