# django - {% blocktrans %} {{rendered_variable}} {% endblocktrans %}

Tags: python, django

django trans is not working for me in this case:

```
{% blocktrans %} {{sign}} {% endblocktrans %}
```

the `{{sign}}` are coming from views.py and are Sunsigns like:

```
'Capricorn'
'Aquarius' 
'Pisces' 
'Aries' 
'Taurus' 
'Gemini' 
'Cancer'
'Leo' 
'Virgo' 
'Libra' 
'Scorpio' 
'Sagittarius'
```

I added into .po file all their translations and did `compilemessages` but it is just not translating it. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This quetion is unclear. So you want to translate the star signs? **How** it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

`blocktrans` is for translating the text around a variable, but it won't translate the variable itself.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813516/django-blocktrans-and-i18n-in-templates) can be helpful for you. More info in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag).

Comment: thanks, I just did this in my models.py:

``_('Scorpio')`` for all of them in this way.. now it is working

Answer (score 0):

I just did the translation in models.py like this:

```
_('Capricorn')
_('Aquarius') 
_('Pisces') 
_('Aries') 
_('Taurus') 
_('Gemini') 
_('Cancer')
_('Leo') 
_('Virgo') 
_('Libra') 
_('Scorpio') 
_('Sagittarius')
```

and in template just

```
{{sign}}
```

and it is working.